# minted : changing fontfamily to support UTF8 chars

Tags: fonts, minted

I'd like to print out the output of a "/usr/bin/tree" command.

For instance :

```
/etc/puppet/hieradata/
├── common.yaml
└── virtual
    ├── false.yaml
    └── true.yaml
```

My idea was to put this in a minted environment. But the fontfamily would not contain the UTF8 caracters like :

```
Missing character: There is no ├ in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text!
```

I tried some other fontfamilies (like dejavusansmono), but no luck with this.

Is there a fontfamily wich provides these characters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `xelatex` and the CMU Typewriter Text font.

---

These fonts are proved to work:

- CMU Typewriter Text
- DejaVu Sans Mono
- Liberation Mono
- Linux Libertine Mono O

These are proved to fail:

- Latin Modern Mono (shows no symbol)
- Bitstream Vera Sans Mono (shows boxes)
- Droid Sans Mono (shows boxes)
- Nimbus Mono L (shows no symbol)

---

Typeset with `xelatex -shell-escape`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{fontspec,minted}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{text}
/etc/puppet/hieradata/
├── common.yaml
└── virtual
    ├── false.yaml
    └── true.yaml
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

> [image]